# (Windows - Python issue) Unable to create venv in directory "venv" exit code: 1

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, python-3.10, stable-diffusion

I'm trying to install stable diffusion on windows, but i got an error that i cant find a fix for. Seems like noone is having the same issue. I posted the question on their github page also but no response so I'm hoping i have better luck here.

I have a .bat file that i have to run and it gets to the folowing lines of code:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('CALL %PYTHON% -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"') do set PYTHON_FULLNAME="%%i"
echo Creating venv in directory %VENV_DIR% using python %PYTHON_FULLNAME%
"%PYTHON_FULLNAME%" -m venv "%VENV_DIR%" >tmp/stdout.txt 2>tmp/stderr.txt
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto :activate_venv
echo Unable to create venv in directory "%VENV_DIR%"
goto :show_stdout_stderr
```

At this step it throws the error:

> Error: Command '['E:\Stable Diffusion\test\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\Scripts\python.exe', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

[image]

So it cant create the venv, but i dont understand why.

I have python 3.10.6 (same as stabel diffusion requires) and pip 20.3.3 (found out that this version is compatible with python 3.10.6)

What i have tried:

- reinstalling python (3.10.6) and launcher (checked install for all users and add to PATH)
- setting the python path in the webui-user.bat file as follows:
- set PYTHON="C:\Users\baias\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe" (I have tried without "" also)
- opening the cmd as administrator and running the .bat
- restarting the computer
- removing the venv file each time its created but complete (after each run attempt)
- cloning the project again

I'm trying to fix this for too long now and i ran out of things to try.

Any sugestions would be greatly apreciated.